# calling destructor using delete

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator

Is it correct to do the following :

```
MyClass mc1(1, 1);
MyClass* pmc1 = &mc1;
delete pmc1;
```

I saw it in a code example. I thought we can call delete on pointers to object that is allocated on the heap but this pointer points to an object on the stack, isn't it ?
Could someone explain it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. You should never call `delete` on a pointer to the object that hasn't been created using `new`. It is undefined behavior.

C++ Standard n3337 **§** 5.3.5/2 Delete

> (...)the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value, a
>   pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or
>   a pointer to a subobject (1.8) representing a base class of such an
>   object (Clause 10). If not, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: So what I thought is correct and the code snippet doing something wrong ? nevertheless what would happen if I call delete on a pointer to an object on the stack ?

Comment: abort() will be called by malloc and signal error code 6 [will be received](http://ideone.com/do0x0n) by a program

Comment: @0d0a, It's undefined behaviour. There's absolutely no guarantee of that happening.

Comment: @chris of course this is correct - SIGABRT is just coincidence here, thank you for the warning